# SignalR client fails to connect when configuring option.AccessTokenProvider

Tags: signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

This connects:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl('/ArgoRtc/Hub')
   .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
   .build();
```

This fails to connect:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl('/ArgoRtc/Hub', options => {
      options.AccessTokenProvider = () => {
         return 'test';                   
      };
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
```

Only difference is that `options.AccessTokenProvider` is configured.

Client error is:
SignalR connection failed: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports. WebSockets failed: Error: 'WebSockets' is disabled by the client. ServerSentEvents failed: Error: 'ServerSentEvents' is disabled by the client. LongPolling failed: Error: 'LongPolling' is disabled by the client.

Obviously none of these transports are disabled because it connects fine without AccessTokenProvider option set. I don't have any type of authentication configured on the server side.

All I want is to be able to read my "test" token string on server through:

```
var authToken = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
```

Which I later plan to custom authenticate myself through hub filters.

Comment: Hi @Brobic Vripiat, I think you need check this document about [Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AccessTokenProvider is now accessTokenFactory. So many changes to this API over the years and so many examples out there from different versions that this can get confusing.

Also docs have always been misleading on how the access token is refreshed. They implied that accessTokenFactory is called on every method call but in reality it only does on initial connection. Wished in wasn't so because now I have to pass new tokens through hub method props which is ugly.